# Dynamic hash - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

the code so far:

```
def queryConnect
    ...
    count = 0

    #clients is an array of hashes.
    #channels is an array of hashes.

    channel_array = []

    channels.each do |channel|
        begin
            if clients[count]["cid"].to_i == channel["cid"].to_i
                channel_array << { "cname" => channel["channel_name"].transform_escape, 
                                   "name"  => clients[count]["client_nickname"].transform_escape }
                count = count + 1
            else
                channel_array << { "cname" => channel["channel_name"].transform_escape }
            end
        rescue
            #transform_escape -> some elements are not type string.
        end
    end
    count = 0
    channel_array
end
```

channels sample input: `[{"channel_name" => "game1", "cid" => 1}, {"channel_name" => "game2", "cid" => 2}, {"channel_name" => "game3", "cid" => 3}]`

clients sample input: `[{"client_nickname" => "greg", "cid" => 1}, {"client_nickname" => "bob", "cid" => 1}, {"client_nickname" => "george", "cid" => 3}]`

expected output:`[{"cname" => "game1", "name" => ["greg", "bob"]}]`

The problem: I'm trying to loop through all the channels, if the client's channel id and channel's channel id (cid) match I want to create a hash with the channel name and client name(s) and then push it onto the `channel_array`.

The only issue I'm having now is when there are multiple clients in a channel... How can I dynamically add a key, value pair by iterating through the clients array and still maintaining the condition to see if the channel ids match?

I've been beating my head against my text editor for two days on this problem any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and expected output? It's really not that clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sample input and expected output added.

Comment: i think this hash doc can help u a bit.http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

```
channel_array << { "cname" => channel["channel_name"], "name" => clients.inject([]){ |m, c| m << c["client_nickname"] if c["cid"] == channel["cid"]; m} }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
channels = [{"channel_name" => "game1", "cid" => 1}, 
            {"channel_name" => "game2", "cid" => 2}, 
            {"channel_name" => "game3", "cid" => 3}]
clients = [{"client_nickname" => "greg", "cid" => 1}, 
           {"client_nickname" => "bob", "cid" => 1}, 
           {"client_nickname" => "george", "cid" => 3}]

channel_data = channels.inject({}){|m, c| m[c["cid"]] = c["channel_name"]; m}
=> {1 => "game1", 2 => "game2", 3 => "game3"}

client_data = clients.inject({}){ |m, c| 
  m[c["cid"]] ||= []
  m[c["cid"]] << c["client_nickname"]
  m
}
=> { 1 => ["greg", "bob"], 3 => ["george"] }

channel_data.map{|cid, cname| 
  {"cname" => cname, "name" => client_data[cid]} if client_data[cid]
}.compact
=> [{"cname" => "game1", "name" => ["greg", "bob"]}, {"cname" => "game3", "name" => ["george"]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track.